# CSS: Relative positioning without updating flow

Tags: css

How can I place an object without updating the flow of other objects, but specify coordinates relative to the parent?

To clarify,

`position: relative; top: -30px; left: 600px;` updates the flow of following objects,
`position: absolute; top: -30px; left: 600px;` doesn't update flow but is relative positioning.

I need not to update the flow, but to specify relative positioning. I can also use Javascript solution.

EDIT

I think a better example would be this:
I have a document, I now want to place a <p> which displays over the existing document without changing the flow (think of a watermark). I also have some specific <div class='abc'>, with respect to which I know that I want to place the new <p> at say coordinates (600,-30).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what I was looking for is `width:0;height:0;` so that the flow after is not realigned because of this element. I wasn't sure initially however, that the object will be displayed at all if I set it to have 0 dimensions.

Answer (score 13):

Apply `position: relative;` to the parent element, and use `position: absolute; top: whatever; left: whatever` on the child element. You can also use a `z-index: something` to make the original content of the parent element overlap the child element with the absolute positioning.

Not sure if I totally get what you mean, though... And I think this is supposed to be on http://www.doctype.com/, because it isn't really about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm not understanding your question correctly, but the flow is also depending on the positioning type (absolute/relative) of the parent. Please note that this can also be inherited, from its parent, etc.

Comment: What I meant is for example, say I want to insert a <p> as a watermark in the document without disturbing anything else in terms of layout - and say I want to put this <p> at coordinates 600,-30 from a specific <div class='abc'>

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.abc{background-color:#CFC;width:400px;position:relative;margin-left:80px;min-height:190px;padding:10px;}
.abc p.watermark{padding:20px;width:100px; position:absolute; top:60px;left:-30px;background-color:#FCF;}
.def{background-color:#9CF;width:300px;margin-top:12px;}
.def p{padding:20px;}
-->
</style></head>

<body>
<div class="abc">
  <p class="watermark">this reacts only to the div it is in</p>
  <p>more text in this div</p>
  <p>that will be overlapped by the paragraph with the class of &quot;watermark.&quot; can't style all &lt;p&gt; in the dive. or each block would overlap each other, and only the top one could be read.</p>
</div>
<div class="def">
   <p class="hi">this one is not affected by the paragraph above</p>
</div>
```

Basically, the div gets relative positioning, the p gets absolute (which is relative to it's relative container, the div). make sure the p is it's own class, not a child of the div.